# Programmatically update the DataProviderJSON Query Text

Tags: web-part, content-search-web-part

```
namespace CSWP
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (SPSite oSie = new SPSite("http://sp14:14583/sites/School"))
            {
                using (SPWeb oWeb = oSie.OpenWeb())
                {

                PublishingWeb publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(oWeb);
                SPFile file = oWeb.GetFile(oWeb.Url + "Pages/Chapter-1.aspx");
                using (SPLimitedWebPartManager wpm = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared))
                {
                    ContentBySearchWebPart csw = new ContentBySearchWebPart();
                    var QuerStrv = new DataProviderScriptWebPart
                    {
                        PropertiesJson = csw.DataProviderJSON
                    };
                    csw.ItemTemplateId = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Content Web Parts/Item_ContentSearch.js";
                    QuerStrv.Properties["QueryTemplate"] = "path:http://sp14:14583/sites/CustomSite ContentTypeId:0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39* (IsDocument:True OR contentclass:STS_ListItem) Title:Chapter-1";

                    csw.DataProviderJSON = QuerStrv.PropertiesJson;
                    wpm.AddWebPart(csw, csw.ZoneID, 0);
                    wpm.SaveChanges(csw);             
                    oWeb.Update();                       
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I am trying to modify the `DataProviderJSON`. My requirement is to get the "Page content" of particular Page in Content search webpart. I am trying to get the page content of `Chapter - 1` here.

What am I missing,  is there anything wrong with my syntax on passing the `DataProviderJsonValue`?

Comment: did you already check this one? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ed5781bd-d1a4-4312-a601-43eba8939fa8/dataproviderjson-not-set-properly-when-creating-contentsearchwebpart-in-programmatically-in?forum=sharepointdevelopment ? They are saying "in addition, in order to override the QueryText attribute, you can override the BeforeSerializeToClient event.". It sounds promising